# Is it possible to find an unknown constant XORed with an unknown array knowing just the resulting array?

Tags: algorithm, math, xor

I have an array of elements `A`. It is calculated by XORing an other array `X` with a constant value `P` following this formula:

```
A[i] = X[i] xor P
```

A is known, X is unknown and P is unknown but **constant** across all elements. Is it possible to find `P` with only those constraints?

Comment: (I think the answer trivial - and the question useful. Think about de-spoiling (`>! `) answers.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a probabilistic prior on the original array, then you can find the most likely P that was used. Simply xor the given array with all possible P, and find the one that maximizes Prob(A).

For example, if you know the original array was something like English text, then you might judge "HELLO" to be more likely than "IDMMN" since HELLO is a word, but IDMMN is not.

If you have no way of judging which input arrays were more or less likely than each other, then you're stuck, since each possible P is equally likely.

Comment: Yeah I have some probabilistic measures on the input arrays. Thanks, for that guidance.

Answer (score 1):

No, since P can be anything. The xor operation is commutative, distributive and associtative, so the following equations are equivalent:

```
A[i] = X[i] xor P
X[i] = A[i] xor P
P = A[i] xor X[i]
etc...
```

All of this is true regardless of P if X is unknown. Of course, you can compute P if you know any pair of A[i] and X[i].

Comment: Yeah, I know that we can not calculate it directly. But, I am wondering if we can use the fact that we have multiple known elements `A[i]`s with multiple unknown elements `X[i]`s XORed with the SAME constant value `P`.

Comment: As the other answer stated, not unless you have some other knowledge about A or X.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example where you can't find P is

```
X = [ 0, 1, 1] P = 1 => A = [ 1, 0, 0 ]
X = [ 2, 3, 3] P = 3 => A = [ 1, 0, 0 ]
```